# C# localization not working

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

-EDIT 2- Figured it out, check my answer. I should stop asking questions on StackOverflow, I always figure it out a couple of minutes later :)

I have the following code (well, roughly, with detection and everything at top):

```
Manager = new ResourceManager("EM250.Localization.Application", 
                              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// CurrentCulture being fr-CA in this case
return Manager.GetString(Key, CurrentCulture);
```

So, I manage my localization resources using a custom class I made.

I got two files, one called "Application.resx" and another, "Application.fr-CA.resx". Both are set to "Embedded Resource". When I compile my code, I get a folder called "fr-CA" with the file "Library.resources.dll" in it. Which is completely fine.

Anyone has an idea why my code is not working? I get English strings everywhere.

Note that is not an ASP.NET project but an actual WinForms project.

-EDIT- Should probably post the rest of the code this is the initialization of my Application:

```
        String LocaleLoad;

        if(Configuration.GetString("Language") == null)
        {

            // Detect which if the computer is set in french.
            switch(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
            {
            case "fr":
                LocaleLoad = "fr-CA";
                break;

            default:
                LocaleLoad = "en-CA";
                break;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            LocaleLoad = Configuration.GetString("Language");

        }

        // Initialize the localization class.
        Localization.Initialize(LocaleLoad);
```

And this is my Localization class:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the culture info with the specific culture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Culture">The culture to load.</param>
    public static void Initialize(string Culture)
    {

        CultureInfo NewCulture = new CultureInfo(Culture);

        if(!(Localization.CurrentCulture == null || CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == NewCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName))
        {

            CurrentCulture = NewCulture;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = NewCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = NewCulture;

            OnCultureChanged();

        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = NewCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = NewCulture;

        CurrentCulture = NewCulture;

        foreach(Language Lang in ListLanguages)
        {
            if(Lang.DisplayName == CurrentCulture.NativeName)
            {
                CurrentLanguageValue = Lang;    
            }
        }

        Manager = new ResourceManager("EM250.Localization.Application", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a single entry from the ressource file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Key">The value to get from the ressource file.</param>
    public static string GetString(string Key)
    {

        return Manager.GetString(Key, CurrentCulture);  
    }
```

Comment: What culture are you executing as?

Comment: en-CA, trying to get fr-CA as well. I got a piece of code that detects regional settings and set it to en-CA or fr-CA accordingly. That part works well, as my CurrentCulture changes depending of my regional settings. And I got an override in my application options, which also works.

Comment: Well, if the culture is `en-CA`, then you _should_ get English.

Comment: Well I execute my application with en-CA, but I got an override in my options, as I said, which sets CurrentCulture to fr-CA no matter what. I did try to debug, and my CurrentCulture is set alright. It's like if it doesn't find the fr-CA file properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Ressource ID wasn't set properly for my fr-CA file. My en-CA file was set to "EM250.Localization.Application.resources" and the fr-CA was "Library.Localization.Application.fr-CA.resources"

Answer (score 2):

If set your culture manually don't forget to set CurrentUICulture too:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CA");
```

After that, the correct resource is retrieved.